# setting the values of credit/debit textbox in JSF

Tags: jsf

I have two textbox in jsf

1)creditAmount

2)debit amount

Now if I type in credit textbox, debit textbox should be zero and and viceversa.

How to do it in jsf? I wrote javascript function for it but it's not working. Is there any way to do it in jsf. I am new in jsf?

```
<p:inputText id="debitAmount" value="#{jvDetailsController.selected.debitAmount}" 
    title="#{bundle.CreateJvDetailsTitle_debitAmount}" required="true" 
    requiredMessage="#{bundle.CreateJvDetailsRequiredMessage_debitAmount}">
    <f:convertNumber minFractionDigits="2" pattern="#0.000" />
</p:inputText>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do that with `JSF` `ajax`.

```
 <h:inputText id="credit" value="#{bean.credit}">
   <f:ajax event="blur" render="devit" listener="#{bean.changeDevit}"/>
 </h:inputText>
 <h:inputText id="devit" value="#{bean.devit}">
   <f:ajax event="blur" render="credit" listener="#{bean.changeCredit}"/>
 </h:inputText>
```

Here is corresponding  `ManagedBean`

```
@ManagedBean(name="bean")
class Bean{

      int devit;
      int credit;
      public void changeDevit(){
         devit=0;
      }
      public void changeCredit(){
         credit=0;
      }
    //getter & setter
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. You solved my problem! I was implementing the same thing through javascript but function was not getting fired.. Do u have any idea?

Comment: Using JS you can also do the same thing by firing JS function on <f:ajax/> onevent property. But, using JSF is more simple than JS.

Comment: but I dont want it on focus event.. The value shouldn't disappear in first textbox when I set focus on second textbox..Any idea how to do it?

Comment: When you want to disappear the value? Alternatively you can disappear on blur event.

Comment: What I mean is the value shouldn't be disappeared from first textbox when I set focus on second textbox. only second textbox value should be set to zero

Comment: one more thing how to find the length of these two textboxes in bean class.. length() function is giving me error..Kindly reply me. It will be highly appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use primefaces ajax for this like

```
<h:panelGrid columns="3">  
    <h:outputText value="Keyup: " />  

    <p:inputText id="counter">  
        <p:ajax event="keyup" update="out"   
                listener="#{counterBean.increment}"/>  
    </p:inputText>  

    <h:outputText id="out" value="#{counterBean.count}" />  
</h:panelGrid>
```

Hope it will hep.

Comment: No it didn't help me.. I want one textbox to be 0 when user is typing in other textbox and viceversa..but it's value should not disappear upon clicking other textbox